# Multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters: JWT authentication and form login in spring security

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I have spring boot app with thymeleaf. I am using spring security formLogin method for security and now I need to add JWT for only some APIs.

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurations {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetails;

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetails);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)

    public class JWTSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

        @Autowired
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider;

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
        }

        @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

            httpSecurity.csrf().disable()

                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/user/authenticate").permitAll()

                    .antMatchers("/api/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .and().
                    exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

            // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
            httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class FormLoginConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider;

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/admins**").hasAnyRole("SADMIN").antMatchers("/admin/**")
                    .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "SADMIN", "WADMIN").antMatchers("/rest/**")
                    .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "SADMIN", "WADMIN", "USER").antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
                    .anyRequest().permitAll().and().formLogin().loginPage("/sign-in-up")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/signInProcess").usernameParameter("phone").and().logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(false).and().csrf().disable().cors();

        }
    }

}
```

by doing this JWT is working fine as just I need but the formlogin has stopped and calling "/signInProcess" now give 404:
[image: signInProcess is not working]

**NOTE:** if I change the order and make formLogin @order(1) it works again but of course will not work.

Also I tried to combine them both like this now it is both works fine but the problem with exception handling if the JWT authentication error will return formlogin thymeleaf error page :

```java
@Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/admins**").hasAnyRole("SADMIN").antMatchers("/admin/**")
                    .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "SADMIN", "WADMIN").antMatchers("/rest/**")
                    .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "SADMIN", "WADMIN", "USER").antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
                    .antMatchers("/api/user/authenticate").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .anyRequest().permitAll().and().formLogin().loginPage("/sign-in-up")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/signInProcess").usernameParameter("phone").and().logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(false).and().csrf().disable().cors();
            
            http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        }
```

any suggestions to make this work. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters` will process the incoming requests in order.
Since `JWTSecurityConfig` is annotated with `@Order(1)` it will process the requests first.

You have not specified a `antMatcher` for this Adapter, so it will match all requests.
This means that a request will never reach `FormLoginConfigurationAdapter`, since `JWTSecurityConfig` matches them all.

If you want `JWTSecurityConfig` to only apply to certain requests, you can specify an `antMatcher` in your security configuration.
Below is an example:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurations {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class JWTSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
              .requestMatchers(matchers -> matchers
                  .antMatchers("/api/**") // apply JWTSecurityConfig to requests matching "/api/**"
              )
              .authorizeRequests(authz -> authz
                  .anyRequest().authenticated()
              )
              .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public class FormLoginConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
              .authorizeRequests(authz -> authz
                  .anyRequest().authenticated()
              )
              .formLogin();
        }
    }
}
```

For more details on multiple `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, you can see the [multiple `HttpSecurity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.2/reference/html5/#multiple-httpsecurity) section in the Spring Security reference docs.

For more details on the difference between `authorizeRequests()` and `requestMatchers()`, you can see [this Stack Overflow question](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.2/reference/html5/#multiple-httpsecurity).