# Multiple WebSecurityConfig only takes @Order(1)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have 2 class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, one with `@Order(1)` the other with `@Order(2)`.
I want the first one to filter my APIs starting with `/user/**` and the other to filter `/client/**` so I can access localhost:8080/client (to have a login page from Salesforce, then it will allow the client to acess some other /client API).

I have :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
      private OpenLdapAuthenticationProvider openLdapAuthenticationProvider;
      private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
      private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

      public WebSecurityConfig(OpenLdapAuthenticationProvider openLdapAuthenticationProvider,
                                 JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint,
                                 JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter) {
            this.openLdapAuthenticationProvider = openLdapAuthenticationProvider;
            this.jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint = jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
            this.jwtRequestFilter = jwtRequestFilter;

        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(openLdapAuthenticationProvider);
        }


        @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            //  CORS
            httpSecurity.cors().and().antMatcher("/**").csrf().disable().sessionManagement();
                    
            httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().deny()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()             
 .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
            
            // JWT Filter
            httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
            
        }
}
```

And the second configuration :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(2)
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigSF extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    MyOAuth2UserService myOAuth2UserService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        
        // Configuration du CORS
        httpSecurity.cors().and().antMatcher("/**").csrf().disable().sessionManagement();

        
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().deny()
        .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/client/**","/client").authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login();
                
    }
}
```

What happens is that when I call `/user` it works (can access all /user APIs), but when I try `/client` it doesn't (error Oauth2).
When I switch order, I can access `localhost8080:/client` and log in into Salesforce no problem but all `/user` APIs are not filtered, meaning I can access them without any JWT in the header.

Is what I want even possible ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters: JWT authentication and form login in spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65654804/multiple-websecurityconfigureradapters-jwt-authentication-and-form-login-in-spr)

Comment: The key point is understanding the difference between `authorizeRequests()` and `requestMatchers()`. See the linked question for more details.

Comment: Yes that was it, thank you!