# Spring security - Simple Multi Security now working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I am dealing with this, since 7 hours ago ,and I cant find an explanation, for simplicity, I just did the example a little smaller.
I need some URLs with security access (JWT), and other path (dashboard) with a form login.

This is my code:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}

@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .csrf().disable()
                // Get Request and /Authenticate do not need authentication
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate", "/authenticate/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll()
                // all others do need authentication
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}

@Configuration
public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/dashboard/index.html").authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }
}
```

This example is working, the JWT mechanism works great.
The only thing it does not work, is the form login. When I hit the browser `localhost:8080/dashboard/index.html`, the file appears.

This is what I need:

/authorize ***-->*** Anyone can hit that URL to get the JWT token

/api ***-->*** Get methods do not need authorization

/api ***-->*** All others verbs, do need a token.

/dashboard/index.html ***-->*** A form login should appear.

I know that `anyRequest().authenticated()`, it is in the first configuration but if I even comment that line, the second `Order` is totally ignored.

What should I add or remove to accomplish my idea?

Comment: Hi ! I tried,but no luck. Even if i remove the Order ,i get :Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters: JWT authentication and form login in spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65654804/multiple-websecurityconfigureradapters-jwt-authentication-and-form-login-in-spr)

Comment: Hi ! Yes,i tried that before but 2 problems:
1-The given/solution code does not compile, I added and() after each authenticated() method
2-After doing that correction, in the browser when I hit /dashboard I see a login, that is ok . But when i try to reach my API using for example Postman and I hit localhost:8080/api/whatever ,the response is the html of the login page !

Comment: Look ,i created a gist with the answer you gave in the post you mention.
https://gist.github.com/alexisjk/ea1fa42b043ab885ad782e9fd024010d
I can make it work the autenticate URL ,the /admin url (I see a form login), BUT anyone can hit /api and that url should be authenticated.

Comment: Did you try `@Ordered(Order.HighestPrecedence + 99)` ?

Comment: Amit Mishra ,i tried ,but no luck . I guess there is something wrong with my mapping . Could you check mi Gist file?

Answer (score 1):

In your `FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, the `antMatchers()` should be called before `authorizeRequests()` - this indicate that this filter chain only apply request to `/dashboard/index.html`.

```java
http.antMatcher("/dashboard/index.html")
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated() // since this filter chain only apply to /dashboard/index.html, don't need use antMatchers() to check again
        .and()
    .formLogin();
```

For more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#multiple-httpsecurity

The second issue is that the Order of your`FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` must be before (less than) `ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter`. **`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` has a default @Order of `100`**, so you should annotate `@Order(0)` on your `FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your time. I tried that,but no luck. I had to change http.antMatchers for http.antMatcher ,because it does not compile.
When i hit localhost:8080/dashboard/index.html,i get : 

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Jul 05 09:43:44 ART 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).

It seems,the other filter (JWT) it s beeing applied again.

Comment: The funny thing now, it s if I remove ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter ,I still get the same Whitelabel error than I told you above . This is a Puzzle!

Comment: The only way i have to make  the form appears is doing this:
   http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/dashboard/index.html").authenticated().and().formLogin();

But now,the problem is that any request to the /api returns 403,even /authenticate that has a permitAll rule. Very strange

Comment: @AlexisYair `http.antMatcher` is correct, Dickson made a typo. But you also have to chnage the order as Dickson wrote. However, you have also another problem, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314176/filter-invoke-twice-when-register-as-spring-bean

Comment: Yes I typo, I have updated the answer. But other than that, it should works. Can you show your debug log/exception stack trace of the 403 response?