# Use several spring security configuration and apply them according to the calling url

Tags: spring-security, okta

I currently have a backend application that implements a very simple Spring security based on login / password that must be added in the http headers.

I also have a front end that uses OKTA as a provider and works with JWT tokens.

I now want to make the end points dedicated to the front end applications use the JWT token system and all the others use the current login/password system.

I can make my application work with an OKTA configuration or with a login / password configuration but I can't make both work together.

Looking at the different messages on stack overflow I have implemented a double configuration but it is always the first one that is applied. The second one is simply ignored and the endpoints of the perimeter are allowed without any token or login / password

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class OauthOktaConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable();

        http
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/end-point/**").authenticated()
                .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();

        Okta.configureResourceServer401ResponseBody(http);
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class StandardSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${http.auth-app-id-header-name}")
    private String appIdRequestHeaderName;
    @Value("${http.auth-api-key-header-name}")
    private String apiKeyRequestHeaderName;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public StandardSecurityConfigurationAdapter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super();
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().addFilter(initAuthenticationFilter())
                .antMatcher("/api/v1/tools/**")
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    private RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter initAuthenticationFilter() {
        RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter(appIdRequestHeaderName,
                apiKeyRequestHeaderName);
        requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setContinueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication(false);
        requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        return requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter;
    }
}

@Override
@Bean
@Primary
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
}
```

In this code, configuration 2 is never used even if I make a call to /api/v1/tools
If I remove configuration 1, configuration 2 is applied.

Can you help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

---

EDIT 1 :

With  the help and suggestion of Eleftheria Stein-Kousathana, i change my configuration (and i add Swagger white list configuration)

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        "/v2/api-docs",
        "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui",
        "/swagger-resources",
        "/swagger-resources/configuration/security",
        "/swagger-ui.html",
        "/webjars/**"
};

@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class SwaggerConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Loading configuration 1");

        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable();

        http
                .requestMatchers(matchers -> matchers.antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST))
                .authorizeRequests(authz -> {
                    authz.anyRequest().permitAll();
                });
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class OauthOktaConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Loading configuration 2");

        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable();

        http
                .requestMatchers(matchers -> matchers.antMatchers("/api/v1/end-point/**"))
                    .authorizeRequests(authz -> {
                        try {
                            authz.anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });

        Okta.configureResourceServer401ResponseBody(http);
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(3)
public static class StandardSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${algo.http.auth-app-id-header-name}")
    private String appIdRequestHeaderName;
    @Value("${algo.http.auth-api-key-header-name}")
    private String apiKeyRequestHeaderName;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public StandardSecurityConfigurationAdapter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super();
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Loading configuration 3");

        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().addFilter(initAuthenticationFilter())
                .requestMatchers(matchers -> matchers.antMatchers("/api/**"))
                .authorizeRequests(authz -> {
                    try {
                        authz.anyRequest().authenticated();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
    }

    private RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter initAuthenticationFilter() {
        RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter(appIdRequestHeaderName,
                apiKeyRequestHeaderName);
        requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setContinueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication(false);
        requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        return requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter;
    }
}

@Override
@Bean
@Primary
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
}
```

I feel that I am very close to succeeding

- Swaggers is accessible when not authenticated
- The routes corresponding to "/api/v1/end-point/**" need a JWT token otherwise I get a 401 error
- The routes corresponding to "/api/** " need a login / password otherwise I get a 401 error

But now I have the following error:

Every time I request a page under swagger or make a call to my api, my web browser asks me for a login / password.

If I cancel I can still navigate on Swagger UI and make call to "/api/v1/end-point/**".
Every Login / password are rejected even they are valid in configuration 3.

If I don't fill the login / password and make a call to any route of "/api/**" i got the following error :

```
2021-07-23 14:49:16.642 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] INFO  c.c.a.a.c.CorrelationIdLoggingAspect - Calling api.controller.endpoint.getActivities executed in 197ms.
2021-07-23 14:49:22.247 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/secret] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy236.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:501)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor220.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy236.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:501)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters: JWT authentication and form login in spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65654804/multiple-websecurityconfigureradapters-jwt-authentication-and-form-login-in-spr)

Comment: The solution proposed in the link would answer my problem however I can't do as in the example :

           http .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**").authorizeRequests() 

in my case "authorizeRequests" is not a method found after using requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**") and i don't know why

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that error @CrYoSoRe! You can either use `.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**").and().authorizeRequests(...)` or lambda notation `.requestMatchers(matchers -> matchers.antMatchers("/api/**")).authorizeRequests(...)`

Comment: Your welcome and thanks for your help :)
With your suggestion i change my code and updated my first message.
I still got error but i think it's better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for all the answers.
We found the solution thanks your help.

Here the final code for helping everyone who needs to do the same things as us. ​

***Security configuration :***

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui",
            "/swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**"
    };

    @Order(1)
    @Configuration
    public static class OauthOktaConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


            http
                    .antMatcher("/api/v1/end-point/**")
                    .authorizeRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
                    .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                    .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) ->
                            sessionManagement
                                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    )
                    .cors(withDefaults())
                    .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable);

            Okta.configureResourceServer401ResponseBody(http);
        }
    }

    @Order(2)
    @Configuration
    public static class StandardSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Value("${http.app-id-header-name}")
        private String appIdRequestHeaderName;
        @Value("${http.api-key-header-name}")
        private String apiKeyRequestHeaderName;

        private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        public StandardSecurityConfigurationAdapter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
            super();
            this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                    .addFilterAt(initAuthenticationFilter(), UsernameRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .authorizeRequests((authorizeRequests) ->
                            authorizeRequests
                                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                    .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) ->
                            sessionManagement
                                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    )
                    .cors(withDefaults())
                    .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable);
        }

        private UsernameRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter initAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
            UsernameRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter usernameRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter = new UsernameRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
            usernameRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
            usernameRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setUsernameParameter(appIdRequestHeaderName);
            usernameRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setPasswordParameter(apiKeyRequestHeaderName);
            usernameRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE);
            usernameRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setPostOnly(false);
            usernameRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                // Do nothing
            });
            return usernameRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter;
        }
    }
}
```

***Authentication filter :***

```
public class UsernameRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader(getUsernameParameter());
    }

    @Override
    protected String obtainPassword(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader(getPasswordParameter());
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {

        super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
    }
}
```

We have also adapted our AuthenticationManager to use UserAuthorities

Thanks again to all

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your program sketch and description correctly, let me attempt to summarize. Your application seeks to support the following:

1. Serve up swagger UI to the public and allow browsing of API definitions.
2. Use authenticated API endpoints (prefixed by `/api/v1/end-point`) with an Okta-provided JWT from another client (not swagger).
3. Use authenticated API endpoints (prefixed by `/api`, *but not `/api/v1/end-point`*) via swagger with username/password as headers.

**Note:** I'm not going to cover how to configure Okta as a provider here, nor configuring swagger. If those steps are not done correctly, you may still have issues.

As far as Spring Security, I think your main issue is due to the fact that you don't appear to have configured an authentication provider for your header-based configuration. This is typically done via a `UserDetailsService` (see section on [UserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-userdetailsservice)):

```java
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    // @formatter:off
    UserDetails userDetails = User.builder()
        .username("api-client")
        .password("{noop}my-api-key")
        .roles("USER")
        .build();
    // @formatter:on

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
}
```

This is obviously an example not meant for production. But the important point is that you have to provide a way for Spring Security  to determine that the credentials are valid. Whether it's a user's username/password, or an API client's appId/apiKey, the `principal` (see [Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-authentication)) is looked up through a `UserDetailsService`, and then the credentials are validated by the `AuthenticationProvider`.

Unfortunately, the built-in `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter` is built on top of a different type of provider that assumes you are pre-authenticated, and is therefore incompatible with username/password authentication. While you could work around this by adapting one type of provider to another, it's more straight forward (at least for example purposes) to adapt the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` to your use case. For example:

```java
private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
        @Override
        protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return request.getHeader(getUsernameParameter());
        }

        @Override
        protected String obtainPassword(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return request.getHeader(getPasswordParameter());
        }

        @Override
        protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
            super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    };
    usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setUsernameParameter(appIdRequestHeaderName);
    usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setPasswordParameter(apiKeyRequestHeaderName);
    usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE);
    usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setPostOnly(false);
    usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
        // Do nothing
    });
    return usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
}
```

If you're interested in making this feel more built-in, check out the section of the docs on [custom DSLs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#jc-custom-dsls).

I would also suggest you override the `configure(WebSecurity web)` method in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to perform your `permitAll` and condense the configuration down to two, as well as eliminating the `/api/**` pattern so your entire application is secure by default. Here's a full example (omitting any Okta-specific code) that also demonstrates correct usage of the Spring Security lambda DSL:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        "/v2/api-docs",
        "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui",
        "/swagger-resources",
        "/swagger-resources/configuration/security",
        "/swagger-ui.html",
        "/webjars/**"
    };

    @Order(1)
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public static class OauthOktaConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/v1/end-point/**")
                .authorizeRequests((authorizeRequests) ->
                    authorizeRequests
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) ->
                    sessionManagement
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable);
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

    @Order(2)
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public static class StandardSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Value("${algo.http.auth-app-id-header-name}")
        private String appIdRequestHeaderName;

        @Value("${algo.http.auth-api-key-header-name}")
        private String apiKeyRequestHeaderName;

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .addFilterAt(usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests((authorizeRequests) ->
                    authorizeRequests
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) ->
                    sessionManagement
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
                @Override
                protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
                    return request.getHeader(getUsernameParameter());
                }

                @Override
                protected String obtainPassword(HttpServletRequest request) {
                    return request.getHeader(getPasswordParameter());
                }

                @Override
                protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            };
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setUsernameParameter(appIdRequestHeaderName);
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setPasswordParameter(apiKeyRequestHeaderName);
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE);
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setPostOnly(false);
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                // Do nothing
            });
            return usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
        }

        @Bean
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            // @formatter:off
            UserDetails userDetails = User.builder()
                .username("api-client")
                .password("{noop}my-api-key")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
            // @formatter:on

            return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
        }

    }

}
```

**Final note:** One caveat is that I included disabling CSRF, which you have done. This is only a [reasonable thing to do](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#csrf-when) if you don't intend to use this application in a web browser with sessions. Since I marked both configurations as stateless (your Okta+JWT example was not), this seems reasonable. Most of the time, however, you really don't want to disable CSRF protection, especially if the reason is "I can't figure out how to make my UI application work with CSRF enabled."

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you very much for your help.
I took the time to respond because I wanted to understand your answer.

You are right about the description of the sketch I am trying to implement.
With your configuration I can now access Swagger without any login/password.

The first configuration (OKTA) works fine and I think the last one (login / password) does too.

I now face one last error when I try to access the routes
protected by login and password.
I am facing an issue where Spring throws an "org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken" exception.

I am looking to resolve this issue and I think everything will work after that.

Let me modestly point out that the setter methods :

```
requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setPrincipalRequestHeader(appIdRequestHeaderName);
requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setCredentialsRequestHeader(apiKeyRequestHeaderName);
```

are not accessible and I keep setting them by constructor.

```
RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter(appIdRequestHeaderName, apiKeyRequestHeaderName)
```

Comment: What version of Spring Security (e.g. spring-security-config) are you using?

Comment: Also, what jar does the `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter` class come from? It's possible we're not talking about the same thing.

Comment: I'm using spring-boot-starter-parent:2.2.4-RELEASE and spring-security-config:5.2.1.RELEASE. 
RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter is a custom class from our back-end witch implement AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter

Comment: Any reason why you have a custom class? There's exactly that class available in spring-security-web.

Comment: We had to retrieve two pieces of information from the headers (appId and appKey) and make sure that this information was present, otherwise we had to redefine the error messages and return them as JSON.
This implementation looked like a good solution for me. 
We had to retrieve two pieces of information from the headers (appId and appKey) and make sure that this information was present, otherwise we had to redefine the error messages and return them as JSON.

This implementation looked like a good solution to me.
I can post the code if you wish

Comment: I trying with only RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter from Spring and still have same issue

Comment: I updated my answer based on your feedback. I forgot that the `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter` does not work with the built-in username/password mechanism, and uses a different provider. You'll want to use `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` (see updated answer), or look into the simpler `AuthenticationFilter`, which may suit your needs as well (I haven't tested that approach).