# How to define basic authentication and a custom filter to different paths

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to implement basic authentication and custom jwt authentication to different paths.

```
http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/basicAuth/**").hasAnyAuthority(SOMEROLE)
            .antMatchers("/signIn").permitAll()
            // Our private endpoints
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();

http.antMatcher("/jwtAuth/**").addFilterBefore(
            jwtAuthenticationFilter(),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
    );
```

ıf I remove jwtAuthenticationFilter basic authentication works fine.
If I add jwtAuthenticationFilter basic authentication does not work. But for "/jwtAuth/**" paths jwtAuthenticationFilter works fine.

I want them together but not on same paths.

*SignIn path is for generating jwt*

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You need 2 different security configurations. See this post for an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65654804/multiple-websecurityconfigureradapters-jwt-authentication-and-form-login-in-spr

Comment: Thank you. this post solved my problem.

Comment: spring security has built in support for jwt for the past 3 years now. Writing a custom jwt security filter is bad practice. So you know.