# Multiple Web Security Configuration : JWT authentication and form login in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

I have a Spring Boot application with Thymeleaf for the front-end and Spring Security's formLogin method for authentication. Now, I need to enhance the security by adding JWT authentication specifically for certain APIs. If I comment `APISecurity` class Form Login does work, and if I comment `WebSecurity` class, then I can login using the postman via the API. My question is how can I get both Form login and API login to work inside the `SecurityConfiguration` class.

```
package com.example.exam.security;

import com.example.exam.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.exam.security.jwt.JwtRequestFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> userRepository.findByEmail(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found."));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public static JwtRequestFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new JwtRequestFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source =
                new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }


    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class APISecurity {
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain apiSecurityConfigure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            return http.cors(withDefaults())
                    .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/login", "/api/v1/auth/register", "api/v1/auth/test").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                    .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                    .sessionManagement(httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer -> httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                    .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class WebSecurity {
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                            .requestMatchers("/registration/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                    .formLogin((form) -> form
                            .loginPage("/login")
                            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                            .defaultSuccessUrl("/secure")
                            .permitAll()
                    )
                    .logout((logout) -> logout
                            .logoutUrl("/logout")
                            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                            .permitAll()
                    );
            return http.build();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/images/**", "/js/**", "/webjars/**");
    }
}
```

[Form Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y4FC.png)
[Rest API login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ngLG.png)

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65654804/multiple-websecurityconfigureradapters-jwt-authentication-and-form-login-in-spr/65664998#65664998

Comment: @dur I tried and it didn’t work.

Comment: @JohnJ What did you try?